# How constexpr deduces the value?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I was going through the program mentioned in cppreference.com for LiteralTypes.
(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType)

I know that constexpr deduces the value during compile time.
But in the below case line 10, 12 and 16 doesn't know the input parameters directly. (at least I can't make out)

Then how is it deducing the value?

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <stdexcept>
  3 
  4 class conststr
  5 {
  6     const char* p;
  7     std::size_t sz;
  8 public:
  9     template<std::size_t N>
 10     constexpr conststr(const char(&a)[N]) : p(a), sz(N - 1) {}
 11 
 12     constexpr char operator[](std::size_t n) const
 13     {
 14         return n < sz ? p[n] : throw std::out_of_range("");
 15     }
 16     constexpr std::size_t size() const { return sz; }
 17 };
 18 
 19 constexpr std::size_t countlower(conststr s, std::size_t n = 0,
 20                                              std::size_t c = 0)
 21 {
 22     return n == s.size() ? c :
 23            s[n] >= 'a' && s[n] <= 'z' ? countlower(s, n + 1, c + 1) :
 24                                         countlower(s, n + 1, c);
 25 }
 26 
 27 // output function that requires a compile-time constant, for testing
 28 template<int n>
 29 struct constN
 30 {
 31     constN() { std::cout << n << '\n'; }
 32 };
 33 
 34 int main()
 35 {
 36     std::cout << "the number of lowercase letters in \"Hello, world!\" is ";
 37     constN<countlower("Hello, world!")>(); // implicitly converted to conststr
 38 }
```

Comment: Note: deleted my answer because, though correct, it was irrelevant to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When line 37 is reached `constN<countlower("Hello, world!")>();` then compiler attempts to deduce the value and replace it in place.

So compiler calls function `countlower("Hello, world!")`. Parameters `std::size_t n = 0, std::size_t c = 0` are then set to their defaults as they weren't passed in.

The function body consists of recursion `return n == s.size() ? c : s[n] >= 'a' && s[n] <= 'z' ? countlower(s, n + 1, c + 1) : countlower(s, n + 1, c);` Where parameters `n` and `c` are incremented on each iteration.

`n` is an index for marking the position of a character that is currently tested.
`c` denotes number of lower letters.

When `n` reaches the end-index, all recursion calls return value and final value is reached. That value is passed as a template argument defined at line 28 `template<int n>` and new `constN` object is constructed.

That all is done at compile time.

## Second look

Imagine the compiler as another `C++` program that defines a recursion function that counts the number of lower characters in a passed string and returns an object with the number as its member.

So this:

`constN<countlower("Hello, world!")>();`

Is then replaced with this:

`constN<9>();`

## The constructor

Ok. So lets imagine the `constN` struct as a normal struct or class like this:

```
struct constN
{
    int n;

    // constructor for the object taking one argument
    constN(int n) : n(n) {};
}
```

After a casual call like `constN(9)` we get an object with `n = 9`. Now template arguments are just like that but instead you pass them in the sharp brackets `<>`.

So these are equal:

```
struct CasualObject
{
    int n;

    CasualObject(int n) : n(n) {};
}

template<int n>
struct YourObject
{
    YourObject() { std::cout << n << '\n'; }
};

CasualconstN(9) == YourconstN<9>()
```

Now lets say the `countlower` function is just a normal function that returns some integer. So you could call the function before the creation of an object which passes the result of the function to the constructor.

So these are equals:

```
int a = countlower("Hey");
constN obj1(a);

constN obj2(countlower("Hey"));

obj1 == obj2;
```

In the end the compiler creates the object with `n = countlower("Hello, world!")`. Now lets pay attention to the only method that `constN` has defined on line 31:

`constN() { std::cout << n << '\n'; }`

Wow. It's a constructor. It has the same name as the type of the object. So not only we call the constructor with `n = 9` basically but we also executes its body. That means `n` is printed to the console.

Lastly, the object `constN` is not assigned to any variable. That means it can never be referenced again. Smart compiler will probably delete line 37 all together and replace it with simple print statement:

`cout << 9 << '\n`;  // There are 9 lowercase letter in "Hello, world!"`

## Implicit conversion

So the question is this: *How does the compiler know what should `N` be when constructing `conststr`?*

To ilustrate, I made a small program:

```
#include <iostream>

class conststr
{
    const char* p;
    std::size_t sz;
public:
    template<std::size_t N>
    constexpr conststr(const char(&a)[N]) : p(a), sz(N - 1) {}
    
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return sz; }
};

int main()
{
    char a[4] = "Hey";
    const char b[4] = "Hey";
    
    conststr x(a);
    conststr y(b);
    conststr z("Hey");
    
    printf("%lu %lu %lu", x.size(), y.size(), z.size());
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you run that, you will get output `3 3 3`. But I here you cry: "There are only 4s in the code and the last object doesn't have a size declared altogether." Let's decipher it bit by bit:

First we create some strings with types `char array` and `const char array` (essentially pointers).

```
char a[4] = "Hey";
const char b[4] = "Hey";
```

They hold 3 letters and a null terminator `\0` which makes it 4 characters. When we create the first `conststr` object:

```
conststr x(a);
```

So we pass variable `a` which is of type `char []`. `char []` can be converted to `const char[]`. It's essentially the same just with `const` modifier. It can also be converted to `std::string` and many others.
So the compiler considers it very similar. So far we have defined this bit of code of the constructor:

```
conststr(const char(&a))
// which can be converted to all of these:
conststr(const char a[])
conststr(char* a)
conststr(char (&a))
```

But there is a template defined:

```
template<std::size_t N>
conststr(const char(&a)[N])
```

To determine what the `N` should be, the compiler tries to rewrite the definition of parameter `a` to suit the functions needs. This is called implicit conversion and has some rules:

- If passed parameters match type, it's fine
- If they do not, attempt a conversion
- If there is conversion, apply it
- If the conversion from passed type to the argument type is not known at compile time, raise a compile error

```
// so from main() we have:
char a[4] = "Hey";
// this can be rewritten like so:
const char a[4] = "Hey";
    
// now it looks very similar to the definition of the constructor:
const char(&a)[N]
const char a[4]
```

As I showed earlier, these are equal. So now, compiler can take what is in the brackets and place it instead of `N`.

Ok. But that's not 3... If we look inside the constructor's "body", we see that the `size sz` is assigned value `N - 1`. And that's our 3.

```
conststr(const char(&a)[N]) : p(a),  sz(N - 1)
conststr(const char a[4]): p("Hey"), sz(4 - 1)
```

Now templates such as `template<std::size_t N>` are just saying to the compiler that the value should be computed or converted at compile time. So you cannot really make up your own `N`, it's always dependent on the length of a string passed in.

Ok, but what about this one:

```
conststr z("Hey");
```

Well again, compiler tries to convert the parameter to a suitable type. And because it takes `const char a[]`, it will be converted to that. And I already covered that.

Comment: Ok. That was really detailed. Thank you.
My doubt now is that when the function `countlower` receives the first parameter`conststr s` it constructs the object of `conststr`. It may be like this in layman words `conststr s = "Hello, world!";` (not sure, but assuming).
When you see the constructor of `conststr`, it has a template argument `N`, how does this gets computed with what value?

Comment: @SSHegde I added last paragraph with some constructor and template arguments explanation.

Comment: Got your point. Understood for `constN` case. Thanks again. But somehow I am unable to understand the below scenario:
When`conststr` object is constructed what value does `N` hold in `const char(&a)[N]`? (Really sorry for dragging this so much)

Comment: @SSHegde Added an `Implicit conversion` part when I try to explain conversions from `char arrays` to `conststr`.

Comment: That cleared all air. Thank you so much. Its a walk in the park now :)